# How to add where clause based on inner query

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to write a query to get count of employees in each department. This i am doing using inner query.
The problem what i am facing is i need to filter out records whose count is less then 10.
Here is how my query looks-

```
SELECT 
   DPT.ID, 
   DPT.NAME, 
   (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM EMPLOYEE E WHERE E.DEPARTMENT_ID=DPT.ID) EMP_COUNT
FROM 
   DEPARTMENT DPT
WHERE 
   EMP_COUNT >=10; -- this part is not working
```

can anyone suggest something i can replace with instead of `EMP_COUNT >=10`  ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why with a subquery? This will probably be faster on most RDBMS-es

```
SELECT     DPT.ID 
,          DPT.NAME 
,          COUNT(*) EMP_COUNT
FROM       DEPARTMENT DPT
INNER JOIN EMPLOYEE E
ON         DPT.ID = E.DEPARTMENT_ID
GROUP BY   DPT.ID 
,          DPT.NAME
HAVING     COUNT(*) >= 10;
```

Comment: this is an excellent suggestion! but will this work for count >= 0?

Comment: @Kshitij: If only you switch to `LEFT JOIN` *(edited:)* and change `COUNT(*)` to something like `COUNT(E.ID)`.

Comment: The count cannot be negative. So, if you want that, just remove the `HAVING` part. If you want departments with 0 employees, use `LEFT JOIN` and `COUNT(E.DEPARTMENT_ID)` instead of `COUNT(*)`, as @Andriy suggested.

Comment: left join OR remvoing having part still doesnt seems to give records with count=0. Yes, count cannot be negative, but i need records with count=0

Comment: replacing COUNT(*) BY COUNT(E.ID) works even for records =0. @Roland plz update this in ur answer

Comment: @Kshitij, I suspect that edit will be considered too radical, Roland, you might care to take it into account (http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/274839)

Comment: @Kshitij, if you want it to worj for 0, why didn't you say so in your question? When I started to write the answer I initially wrote it with a left join, since I learned over time to consider edge cases. When I re-examined your question and noticed that it's ok for you to lose departments with less than 10 empoloyees I rewrote to inner join since that is usually considered more efficient. I don't see any need to edit the answer since it matches the question perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DPT.ID, DPT.NAME, DEPT_EMP_COUNT
FROM DEPARTMENT DPT, (SELECT E.DEPARTMENT_ID , COUNT(1) AS DEPT_EMP_COUNT 
                      FROM EMPLOYEE E
                      GROUP BY E.DEPARTMENT_ID ) EMP_COUNT 
WHERE EMP_COUNT.DEPARTMENT_ID = DPT.ID AND DEPT_EMP_COUNT > 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select dept.deptId,
dept.deptName,
count(emp.empid) as numb_of_emps
from department dept inner join employee emp
on dept.deptid = emp.deptid
group by dept.deptid,dept.deptName
having count(emp.empid) >= 10
```